# How to make jQuery wait until one loop completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++) {
  if (responseJson[i].Framework == "FPS") {
    ExecuteFps(responseJson[i], payload);
  } else if (responseJson[i].Framework == "OATS") {
      var data = responseJson[i];
      // Here i need one iteration to complete all its task and it should allow another one. I mean I want it to run serially.
      $.when(a(responseJson[i], responseJson[i].Path)).done(function() {
        removeItemResponse(data)});
      }

function a(data, folderpath) {
  var def = $.Deferred();

  var template = $("#template").val();
  var ref = JSON.stringify(ref);
  var path = document.getElementById('automationPathText').value;
  var projectId = $("#projectId").val();
  var serverpath = $("#serverPathText").val();
  var parallelProcess = "No";
  //alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

  $.ajax({
    url: "Target",
    data: {
      template: template,
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(responseJson) { 
      //document.IOProcessStream.learnApplication("D:\\AutomationTesting\\","IE","No","D:\\AutomationTesting\\ServerConfiguration\\","No");
      //document.IOProcessStream.generateScript("D:\\AutomationTesting\\","D:\\AutomationTesting\\ServerConfiguration\\");
      if (responseJson.Status === "NOREFERENCE" || responseJson.Status === "SUCCESS") {
          document.IOProcessStream.gateway(path, projectId, folderpath, serverpath, "IE");
          //alert("After document....");
          document.IOProcessStream.executeApplication(folderpath, path, "No", "IE", serverpath, "No", data);
          console.log("IN a");
          def.resolve();    
      }
    }
  });

  return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: Please add some concise details to elaborate your problem like what is the going on right now!

Answer (score 0):

First of all a little bit digging into your code.

1. You should not create a function inside a loop, it is not recommended.
2. The function runs `asynchonosly` because it is making an `Ajax` call inside. That is why loop never waits for it to finish and keep executing.

To get around this, you need to rearrange your code. These things have been explained many times so to keep it simple this is my suggestion to you.

> Move `function a()` outside the loop and give it meaningful name. The second thing would be to wrap the code inside loop in a [closure](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) to capture the value of `i` in each iteration.

This is how it would look.

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++) {
    if (responseJson[i].Framework == "FPS") {
        ExecuteFps(responseJson[i], payload);
    } else if (responseJson[i].Framework == "OATS") {     
        (function(i){
            // it will catch i in each iteration!
            var data = responseJson[i];
            $.when(someMeaningFullName(data, data.Path)).done(function() {
                removeItemResponse(data)
            });
        })(i);
    }
}   // loop ends here!

// this is your function a() outside the loop!
function someMeaningFulName(data, folderpath) {
    // same code...
}
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, its not working still same.Pls suggest me something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute using `$.when()`, `Function.prototype.apply()`, `$.map()` for `for` loop; also `$.Deferred()` at `a` function is not necessary, you can `return` `$.ajax()` which returns a jQuery promise object.

Note certain what return values of `ExecuteFps`, `removeItemResponse` functions are?

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(responseJson, function(response, i) {
  if (response.Framework == "FPS") {
         return ExecuteFps(response, payload)
  } else if (response.Framework == "OATS") {
           return a(response, response.Path))
             .done(function() {
               removeItemResponse(response)
             })
}))

function a(data, folderpath) {
  return $.ajax(/* options */)
}
```

Comment: Hi , its not working still same.Pls suggest me something else

Comment: @Ashwini Can you describe "not working"?, create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: Pls check jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Ashwini _"pls check"_ Where to check?

Comment: function executeTemplate()
{$.post(contextRoot + "/FetchTemplateContent",{
template : $("#template").val()},
function(responseJson)
{for(var i=0;i<responseJson.length;i++){
$.when.apply($, $.map(responseJson, function(response, i) {
if(responseJson[i].Framework == "FPS")
{ExecuteFps(responseJson[i],payload);
     }
     else if(responseJson[i].Framework == "OATS")
     {
        var data = responseJson[i];

return a(response, response.Path)
             .done(function() {
               removeItemResponse(response);
        
             });
            } 
})}

Comment: There appear to be two `for` loops and call to `$.map()`, though no `html` at Question? `$.map()` can replace `for` loops

Comment: Hi , could you please share your number, if you don't mind.This is my id duashwini@gmail.i can call you if you share .thanks.